# Is drag coefficent proportional to fuel consumption (car)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, drag, aerodynamics

Car has drag coefficient of 0.35 and drink 5L/100km, if car Cd is reduced to 0.20 and everthying else stay the same(frontal area,power,weight,drive style etc),how much will car drink?

Is it possible to calculate this or we need something more?

I am interested if exist direct link/formula between Cd and fuel consumption?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation $F_d\propto{}c_d$ Drag _force_ is directly proportional to the coefficient. IDK how that relates to fuel consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Car spent fuel energy not only for overcoming air resistance, but also for conquering road rolling resistance. Car work done per $100~km$ would be reduced then by :
$$ \frac {W_{optimized}}{W_{original}} = \frac {k+0.20/0.35}{k+1} ~~~~~(1),$$

Where $k= {W_{rr}}/{W_D}$ is the ratio between work done of car for rolling resistance and air drag respectively.

Work done ratio in equation (1) may not have simple linear relationship to a fuel consumption drop ratio, but for a first estimates you can use it as such substitute. However, until you will not know coefficient $k$,- how car divides it's workload between fighting with ground rolling resistance and air resistance,- you can't say anything at all about how lowering drag coefficient affect fuel consumtion in general.